# Display message when one value is selected

Tags: javascript, parsley

Not a complicated one but i have very limited coding knowledge.

Im looking for a message to be display when a value from a select menu (Less than $10,000) is selected and also prevents the form from submitting.

```
<select name="levelofdebt" class="form-control" id="levelofdebt" required>
                                      <option value="" disabled selected="selected">Select total debt</option>
                                      <option value="$10,000 or less">Less than $10,000</option>
                                      <option value="$10-15k">$10,000 - $15,000</option>
                                      <option value="$15-20k">$15,000 - $20,000</option>
                                      <option value="$20-30k">$20,000 - $30,000</option>
                                      <option value="$30-40k">$30,000 - $40,000</option>
                                      <option value="$40-50k">$40,000 - $50,000</option>
                                      <option value="$50-60k">$50,000 - $60,000</option>
                                      <option value="$60-100k">$60,000 - $100,000</option>
                                      <option value="$100k +">$100,000 +</option>
                                    </select>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: add the form html and relevant js

Comment: SO is not for do your homework, Show us what u tried so far and what is the problem with that code. (About the javascript that detect that some item has changed and display the message). Otherwise keep searching in stack overflow, there are a lot of examples to do the thing that you are asking for.

Comment: I did look through stack overflow and found some related answers but as i mentioned, i have limited coding skills and didn't know how to utilise those answers.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function selectchange(){
  if($("#levelofdebt").val() == '$10,000 or less')
    {
        
        alert('Amount Less than $10,000');
      return false; // prevents page reload
    }
  else{
     // Do something
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="levelofdebt" class="form-control" id="levelofdebt" required onchange="return selectchange();">
                                      <option value="" disabled selected="selected">Select total debt</option>
                                      <option value="$10,000 or less">Less than $10,000</option>
                                      <option value="$10-15k">$10,000 - $15,000</option>
                                      <option value="$15-20k">$15,000 - $20,000</option>
                                      <option value="$20-30k">$20,000 - $30,000</option>
                                      <option value="$30-40k">$30,000 - $40,000</option>
                                      <option value="$40-50k">$40,000 - $50,000</option>
                                      <option value="$50-60k">$50,000 - $60,000</option>
                                      <option value="$60-100k">$60,000 - $100,000</option>
                                      <option value="$100k +">$100,000 +</option>
                                    </select>
```